# Why gcc-arm-none-eabi slower for switch: GCC7 vs GCC10

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, regression

For cortexM4, GCC10 produces bigger assembly than GCC7 for very simple switch statements.

Here is the C code example:

*file: switch.c*

```
int switchFunction(int foo) {
  switch (foo) {
  case 0:
    return 0;
  case 1:
    return 1;
  default:
    return -1;
  }
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the toolchain from here [gcc-arm-none-eabi](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads)
Compile command: `arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m4 ./switch.c`
(`--specs=nosys.specs` is just because I do not compile on an ARM architecture.)

For GCC7 it produces this assembly code:

```
000080f8 <switchFunction>:
    80f8:       2801            cmp     r0, #1
    80fa:       bf88            it      hi
    80fc:       f04f 30ff       movhi.w r0, #4294967295 ; 0xffffffff
    8100:       4770            bx      lr
```

While GCC10 produces one more line (25% bigger):

```
00008100 <switchFunction>:
    8100:       b118            cbz     r0, 810a <switchFunction+0xa>
    8102:       2801            cmp     r0, #1
    8104:       bf18            it      ne
    8106:       f04f 30ff       movne.w r0, #4294967295 ; 0xffffffff
    810a:       4770            bx      lr
```

Note: GCC10 produces the same code as if it was a simple if:

```
int ifFunction(int foo) {
  if (foo == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (foo == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

**What is the reason of this change?** Is it because a limitation was discovered?

Comment: This would be a question for GCC development community

Comment: It might have to do with branch-probabilities.

Comment: @thebusybee so you are telling this is a regression from GCC7 to GCC10? Now GCC10 calculates wrong probabilities?

Comment: @EugeneSh. right, I'll ask GCC community

Comment: No, I didn't say so. My comment is a hint for you to investigate in that direction. GCC 10 might interpret the first `case` differently than GCC 7, or GCC 7 might do no analysis at all, and so on. You might try to exchange `case`s to see if that changes anything. Anyway, ask the GCC experts.